# PHP/MYSQL: Using 'CONCAT' and 'AND' clause in MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute this query:

Query 1:

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.title_wo 
          FROM `worksheet_master` AS a 
            INNER JOIN `work_order` AS b ON a.wo_number = b.wo_number 
          WHERE CONCAT (a.`wo_number` like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%', 
                        `title_wo` like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%') 
          ORDER BY a.`wo_number` DESC LIMIT 0,50";
```

Query 2:

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.title_wo 
          FROM `worksheet_master` AS a 
            INNER JOIN `work_order` AS b ON a.wo_number = b.wo_number 
          WHERE CONCAT (a.`wo_number` like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%', 
                        `title_wo` like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%') 
            AND a.`status` = 'NULL' 
          ORDER BY a.`wo_number` DESC 
          LIMIT 0,50";
```

The *Query 2* didn't gave me any result with *AND* clause while the *Query 1* gave me the result.

Can anyone help me with this? I need to sort out the result which has the empty status in my table, that's why I added AND clause in *Query 2* hoping the result will be as expected, but it's not.

Thank You.

Comment: It helps if we can see what you are showing us

Comment: WHAT are you trying to do?  Using boolean expressions as `CONCAT()` arguments is highly non-intuitive.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Pardon me, but I think that the question is clear enough to understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for letting me know, is there any better way then?

Comment: @tadman wow, I didn't know about that. thanks for letting me know! I'll try to migrate and use PDO statement instead, but it'll take a while perhaps.

Comment: Just giving you a heads up. PDO's pretty friendly to use and will make it a lot easier to write correct code, so hope that works out for you.

Comment: @MAnsyori Yes it is now that I edited and cleaned it up

Comment: @tadman Ok thanks man. well, now I think I'm curious about does POST method is injectable? because I didn't use any GET method in my query. I'm using POST method with helps of AJAX method to get the result when user give a type on a text or a.k.a onkeyup function.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh I see, thanks.

Comment: @MAnsyori It's the very fact that you put `$_POST` right into your query that creates problems. Remember, those values can come from anyone, they can be *anything*, not just what you expect your form to submit. You have no control over what comes in on the request, it's trivial to hook up a tool like `curl` or hack around in the browser with the inspector, so it's your responsibility to test everything carefully, validate and escape as necessary. Look at what a tool like [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org) can do given a hole of that sort. It's scary.

Comment: ` AND a.status = 'NULL' ` hum... If you want to return the null status, you have to write it like that :  `AND a.status is NULL` .

Comment: @AlexandreT Yes correct. My bad, I didn't know using '= NULL' and 'IS NULL' are making any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `NULL` is an actual string, you need to use `IS NULL` instead.

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.title_wo 
      FROM `worksheet_master` AS a 
        INNER JOIN `work_order` AS b ON a.wo_number = b.wo_number 
      WHERE CONCAT (a.`wo_number` like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%', 
                    `title_wo` like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%') 
        AND a.`status` IS NULL 
      ORDER BY a.`wo_number` DESC 
      LIMIT 0,50";
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know using '= NULL' and 'IS NULL' are making any difference. The query works, result is good as I expected, will accept this as an answer in 10 mins. Stackoverflow rule. *peace*